# What is the proper way to use CreateRemoteThread to inject code into another process in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, ipc

I read on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/22/191123.aspx) that sysinernals uses `CreateRemoteThread()` to inject `ExitProcess` into another process to terminate it. Is it true? And, if yes, can someone show me how to do it in my Delphi application? I want to terminate the process which started my application.

Comment: 1. Get the PID of the other process. 2. Call OpenProcess on that to get the process handle. Pass the access flags specified in the CreateRemoteThread documentation. 3. Call CreateRemoteThread passing the address of `ExitProcess` in the target process address space. This is the tricky part.

Comment: Anyway, it's all rather pointless. Just call `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just want to give the hackers a headache. Calling `TerminateProcess` would be rather easy to intercept. Don't you agree?

Comment: Would it be easy? Why would it be easier than blocking remote threads? Where do hackers come into this anyway? Also, no real evidence that Process Explorer uses `CreateRemoteThread`. Some random guy on a blog says that he suspects that and you take it as fact.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Long story short, I want to be sure that this release of my application will be time consuming to crack. In the last version, it took a few days to bypass a USB dongle on which I had stored a decryption key. I just want to make sure they have a good time trying to understand what I'm doing. For instance, I have written an application which searches my source files, and renames my procedures and functions to random strings.

Comment: All that you will achieve here is making the code harder for you to understand. The dongle will be cracked as soon as any half decent hacker attempts it. A common hack of protection you describe would be to duplicate the USB dongle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well the application I mentioned copies my source code to another folder, does its job, builds the application and deletes the temporary source files. So my source remains intact. And I agree that dongles are not secure. That's why I have switched to smart cards.

Comment: I expect smart cards are insecure also. Are you reading the contents of the smart card into your app? If so, how can you keep that secure? Also, changing the names of your procedures is utterly pointless. The compiler removes them anyway! You can't see them in your existing app.

Comment: I just found a way [to load a library directly into memory bypassing `LoadLibrary`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171769/how-can-i-execute-code-directly-from-memory-in-delphi) and I'm planning on loading my encryption library directly from smart card into memory. I know it's not bullet proof, but it's a little bit less "less secure" than a dongle. Don't you agree?

Comment: No, I think the hackers will still hack your app. It doesn't matter what you do, you'll be hacked if there is value in doing so. Just make sure you don't make life awkward for your honest paying customers. No point failing to stop the hacking and also drive away the customers that do pay you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you ask here is answered on this blog post: http://private-storm.de/2009/08/11/case-terminateprocess/

This includes Delphi source code. For some reason that code enabled the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege, which is not necessary.

The difficulty with this kind of approach is locating the address of `ExitProcess` in the target app. The code in the article assumes that it's at the same address as in your own process. That's very likely true, but not always. For example, if your process is a 64 bit process and the target process is a 32 bit process then it won't be true. Or if the target process has a base address that doesn't allow kernel32 to load at its preferred address.

Another problem is if your process is 32 bit and the target process is 64 bit. In that case then I believe the `CreateRemoteProcess` trick simply fails.

All in all, I would use `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: The only problem is that (as anticipated) it needs elevation to run correctly when UAC is enabled

Comment: That's probably the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` part. Only yesterday I wrote a Delphi app that calls `CreateRemoteThread` and works admirably with no elevation.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe that line is not needed ;-). I remarked it and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: This is the subject a question that I asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180732/do-i-need-to-adjust-token-privileges-in-order-to-successfully-call-createremotet